# What is the meaning of '育てられ方’ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I would appreciate it if someone could break down the grammar in this sentence for me and offer an English translation. What I am confused about is who the subject in this sentence is and whether '育てられ方' is in passive or some other grammatical form. Also, why 'をする' was used with '育てられ方'

友達が、両親からどのような育てられ方をしましたか。

Comment: This sentence seems a little strange to me. Is it really が that is following 友達?

Comment: It is が. What seems strange about it to you?

Comment: It is far more natural to use は there.

Comment: It lacks the topic marker は. Is this an example sentence of a textbook made by a nonnative speaker? Or is this a part of a longer article? If the latter is the case, could you share the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 友達**は**両親からどのような育てられ方をしましたか。
>   How was *the* friend raised by his/her parents?

`pre-masu form + 方【かた】` forms a noun phrase meaning "way of ～", or "how ～". For example 食べ方 is "the way of eating it" or "how to eat it". Combined with some adjectival expression, it also works as a suru-verb. For example 彼は面白い考え方をする means "His way of thinking is interesting".

- 育てる: "to raise (a child)"
- 育てられる: the passive form of 育てる, "to be raised"
- 育てられ: the pre-masu/continuative form of 育てられる
- 育てられ方: "the way of being raised"

The subject of the whole sentence is 友達, but I believe 友達 should be marked with は because it must be a [definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness) person, i.e., 友達 must have been introduced in the universe of discourse.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you very much.